# Keyboard overlapping textfields in UITableViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uitextfield, uisplitviewcontroller

**UITableViewController automaticly manages textfield editing**: scrolling to editable content, changing insets to display textfield and keyboard on screen simultaneously without keyboard overlapping. It's very cool feature because i don't need to write a lot of code to calculate new insets, scroll to content, check if deviceOrientation changed or keyboard hidden and so on.

But that feature **fails** when we are using **SplitViewController**, after we adding to root that controller automatic management of textfield is working only on Pad-oriented screens. I think that's Apple's bug, but maybe it's my mistake and i'm doing something wrong? I've checked that SplitViewController -> Navigation Controller -> UITableViewController hierarchy is correct in Apple's HID.

I've written simple application for that question so you can see that bug if you want, how can I fix it?

Link to simple, fresh XCode project with that bug: https://www.dropbox.com/s/o315awgonzeskeo/TableEditing.zip?dl=0

[image: SplitViewFresh]

**Semi-solution**: remove SplitViewController if device is iPhone. Everything is working ok on iPad, but not working on iPhone, so we may try that:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let rootController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("navigation") as! UINavigationController
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom != .Pad {
        // setting non-split rootView if device is iPhone
        self.window!.rootViewController = rootController
    }
}
```

But there is problem — we are loosing SplitViewController on iPhone 6 Plus (i checked, on iPhone 6 Plus on portrait orientation keyboard still overlaps, on landscape all is ok). So it's not the solution.

Comment: Strange behavior. In iOS9 it seems that apple fixed the bug, so another special treatment for older versions is necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to handle such situations is to manually control your `UITableView` and move it above keyboard. I've create [small class](https://gist.github.com/Sorix/3647c1368b12b6f84e1ceec301dff7ff) for it, it increases and decreases size of your constraint (it maybe be constraint from `UITableView` to bottom of a view) if keyboard appears/disappears.

Answer (score 0):

Just increase the size of tableview height by either setting content size

```
tableView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(widthYouWant, heightYouWant);
```

or by tableview Bottom Content Insets in frame section of tableview from nib. And then scroll that row to top by calling

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section];
[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```

let me know if this is what you;r looking for

Comment: I don't know height of tableView, there may be a lot of rows with different height. And my field always last in table, so I can't just scroll to it, it will stay at bottom, because it is last element in table.

Comment: I'm not on my Macbook don't know the exact term. Go into your Xib file. Then select tableview, then go to the frame section for right menu section. Then set bottom insets up to 200(Keyboard height)

Comment: bottom content insets

Answer (score 0):

Try to set this code in you're `UITableViewController`:

```
  -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated 
  {
     [super viewWillAppear:YES]; 
  }
```

> Note: UITableViewController has new capabilities in iOS 3.0. A
>   table-view controller supports inline editing of table-view rows; if,
>   for example, rows have embedded text fields in editing mode, it
>   scrolls the row being edited above the virtual keyboard

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/o315awgonzeskeo/TableEditing.zip?dl=0 my fresh test project, please read about SplitViewController (i've updated post).

Answer (score 0):

You may try to add TPKeyboardAvoiding to your project

TPKeyboardAvoiding - A drop-in universal solution for moving text fields out of the way of the keyboard in iOS.

For use with UITableViewController classes, drop TPKeyboardAvoidingTableView.m and TPKeyboardAvoidingTableView.h into your project, and make your UITableView a TPKeyboardAvoidingTableView in the xib.

Comment: I'm looking for native solution, i think that it is exists built-in solution in UITableViewController iOS8.

Answer (score 0):

As an option you can subscribe to keyboard notifications e.g.:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                  selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)
                                    name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                  object:self.view.window];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                  selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:)
                                    name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                  object:self.view.window];
```

And then when keyboard is about to show move your view up on some number of pixels, so last row is visible. And when keyboard hides - move it down.